# Как правильно в сноске указать источник цитаты?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитирование, сноски

**Л. В. Соловьев. («)Повесть о Ходже Насреддине(»). Книга первая «Возмутитель спокойствия».**

- Как правильно в сноске указать источник цитаты: надо ли ставить кавычки  в названии дилогии или только в отношении названия первой книги?

> Л. В. Соловьев. «Повесть о Ходже Насреддине». Книга первая «Возмутитель спокойствия».
>
> Л. В. Соловьев. Повесть о Ходже Насреддине. Книга первая «Возмутитель спокойствия».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**А.** 2. Не выделяются кавычками:
7) названия книг, газет и журналов в библиографических списках, сносках:
Ч у к о в с к и й К. Живой как жизнь. М., 1962
[Д. Э. Розенталь. § 60. Названия литературных произведений...](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=171#pp171)

Правильно, думаю, будет так:
№ сноски. С о л о в ь е в Л.В. Повесть о Ходже Насреддине. Книга первая. Возмутитель спокойствия.
(Фамилия автора выделена р а з р я д к о й.)

**Б.** Фамилии и инициалы авторов цитируемых работ выделяются курсивом, причем инициалы следуют после фамилии, пробел между инициалами отсутствует (*Иванов А.А*.).
Названия цитируемых работ даются без кавычек, название книги должно быть полным.
[Правила оформления сносок](http://philosophy.spbu.ru/userfiles/rusphil/Pravila%20oformleniya%20snosok.pdf)

Или так:
№ сноски. *Соловьев Л.В.* Повесть о Ходже Насреддине. Книга первая. Возмутитель спокойствия.
(Фамилия автора выделена *курсивом*.)

Некоторые особенности цитирования также можно посмотреть [здесь](http://trubnikovann.narod.ru/Ssylki.htm).
(*Сыма Цянь.* Исторические записки (Ши цзи). Т. IV. Перевод с китайского, вступительная статья, комментарий и приложения Р.В. Вяткина. М., 1986.)